# Refactoring map loading switch statement in XNA

Tags: c#, oop, xna

I have a switch statement that takes a tuple and chooses which set of nested switch statements to go into based on the second value of the tuple.  Everything works well enough with this way, but since I need to load 4 maps around the center map for smooth transitions each time the switch statement ends up taking up more space than neccesary.  So, I'm in the process of refactoring to a method, which for now just loads and draws the base sprites.  I've run into a few problems with the content manager receivings null refrence exceptions when the loading the sprites and don't know how to properly pass the content to the Load method.

Here's my abreviated Switch Statements in Draw:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
Map.FindLocation(Map.LocationXY, ZoneDecider);
switch (Map.TupleHolder.Item1)
{
   case 0:
   {
      switch (Map.TupleHolder.Item2)
      {
         case 0:
            if (LoadNextMap)
            {
               if (Right)
               {
                  backgroundCenter.LoadContent(this.Content,"BackgroundBottom");
                  backgroundCenter.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
               }
               else if (Left)
               {
                  backgroundCenter.LoadContent(this.Content, "BackgroundBottom");
                  backgroundCenter.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
               }
               else if (Top)
               {
                  backgroundCenter.LoadContent(this.Content, "BackgroundBottomRight");
                  backgroundCenter.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
               }
               else if(Bottom)
               {
                  backgroundCenter.LoadContent(this.Content, "BackgroundRight");
                  backgroundCenter.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
               }
               backgroundWest.LoadContent(this.Content, "BackgroundBottom");
               backgroundWest.position = new Vector2(westTransition, 0);
               backgroundEast.LoadContent(this.Content, "BackgroundBottomRight");
               backgroundEast.position = new Vector2(eastTransition, 0);
               backgroundNorth.LoadContent(this.Content, "BackgroundMid");
               backgroundNorth.position = new Vector2(0, northTransition);
               backgroundSouth.LoadContent(this.Content, "BackgroundBottomRight");
               backgroundSouth.position = new Vector2(0, southTransition);
               LoadNextMap = false;
            }
            //new SpriteBatch(graphicsDevice)
            backgroundCenter.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
            //Drawbackground.drawBackground(backgroundWest, backgroundEast,
            // backgroundNorth, backgroundSouth);
            backgroundWest.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
            backgroundEast.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
            backgroundNorth.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
            backgroundSouth.Draw(this.spriteBatch);

            break;
```

This isn't ideal, so to start off the refactoring I'm moving the sections out side fo the if statements to a new method.

The new method:

```
public class DrawNextBackground
{
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    ContentManager theContentManager;

    public void drawBackground(Background backgroundWest,
        Background backgroundEast, Background backgroundNorth, Background backgroundSouth)
    {
        float eastTransition = 1068;
        float westTransition = -1068;
        float northTransition = -936;
        float southTransition = 936;

        backgroundWest.LoadContent(this.theContentManager, "BackgroundBottom");
        backgroundWest.position = new Vector2(westTransition, 0);
        backgroundEast.LoadContent(this.theContentManager, "BackgroundBottomRight");
        backgroundEast.position = new Vector2(eastTransition, 0);
        backgroundNorth.LoadContent(this.theContentManager, "BackgroundMid");
        backgroundNorth.position = new Vector2(0, northTransition);
        backgroundSouth.LoadContent(this.theContentManager, "BackgroundBottomRight");
        backgroundSouth.position = new Vector2(0, southTransition);
        backgroundWest.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
        backgroundEast.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
        backgroundNorth.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
        backgroundSouth.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
    }
}
```

The Load Method:

```
    public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager, string theAssetName)
    {
        SpriteSize = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(theAssetName);
    }
```

How may I go about getting the Load method to notice each object has content? Everything I've tried so far hasn't worked.

Comment: how will your smooth transitions looks like? does your sprite allway's be in the center of your window and your map is moving or the other way around and the map is switching if you are walking out of it?

Comment: As I walk out of the map, the next map moves in the direction of the player.  As soon as the next map passes the player, the player starts moving with the map, until he reaches the opposite side.  The transition looks similar to the map switch in Zelda.

Comment: does it works now? or does the null ref still remains?  what is the class type of your original class and what does it inherit

Comment: The original class is background and it has methods for drawing and loading sprites.

Comment: so your `this` in your original is typeOf `Background and inherits nothing` is that right?? so where is your initialization part from  `this.Content` in your original code? because you need to adapt this in your refactored solution

Comment: @WiiMaxx to make a new ContentManager I need to put an argument into the () after ContentManager.  It needs to have iServiceprovider serviceProvider, and a string Directory.  I know the directory name, but not what to put in for the serviceProvider.

Comment: but in your original you know the `serviceProvider` right?

Comment: @WiiMaxx I believe it's defined in the initialize step as `Content.RootDirectory = "Content";`

Comment: I don't see the Service provider explicitly defined in XNA.

Comment: @WiiMaxx Sorry, my responses have been a bit slow.  I'm trying to get delegates working, as well.  I have to run to close.  Afterwards I should have this closer to being figured out.

Comment: If I have an update with slightly different problem, that develops on this issue should I post it here, or start another thread?

Comment: start another thread :-)

Comment: @WiiMaxx It turns out completely respecting OOP is making my code more cumbersome.

Comment: maybe you are creating to much objects you doesn't? how many objects do create? and by cumbersome do you mean the loading from the new map's? or the displaying?

Comment: I have 25 locations with up to 4 possible entrances for each.  I'm just nesting switch statements, since a more ideal solution would take more time at this point.

Comment: please start another thread for this (maybe with some more code) as a better discussion basis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the null content, you must pass the original content manager (in Game1.cs) to your class in order to draw, don't try to create a new one.

```
    //add this to the drawNextBackground class
    //where the content manager in game1.cs is "Content"
    //Content is inherited from another class, and an example
    //should be visible in the LoadContent method in game1.cs        
    public void initialize(ContentManager contentManager)
    {
          theContentManager = contentManager;
    }
```

Comment: That should be able to get the ContentManager I have in my normal draw class?

Comment: I don't see anything initialized as content manager, in game1.cs `Content.RootDirectory = "Content";`

Comment: The ContentManager in game1.cs is called "Content". It is inherited from another class so you will not see the instance variable, but it is called in the LoadContent method. Something like: Content.Load<Texture2D>(...).

Answer (score 2):

ok if i understood you correctly your loading have always 5 Maps (actual map and 4 side maps).

Whats about loading only 3 Maps at Max let's think about it
 
**you know:** 
Player *(Position,Speed,Move direction)*, 
Map *(Size, Walk able directions to leave the Map)*.

Example Map

```
    ---------------------
    | P |   |   |   |   |
    ---------------------
    |   |   |   |   |   |
    ---------------------
    |   |   |   |   |   |
    ---------------------
    |   |   |   |   |   |   P = Player
    ---------------------
```

So now you can say if `P.Position` near to map edge load this map's here it would be top,left 
this will reduce your loading costs

now you can expend this by adding some more details to your map let's named it as Walkdirections

```
    ---------------------
    | X | X | X | X | X |
    ---------------------
    | P |   |   |   |   |
    ---------------------
    |   |   |   |   |   |
    ---------------------
    |   |   |   |   |   |   P = Player
    ---------------------   X = Player can't pass this field
```

so as designer of your map you know he can't go top on Map 14 so you doesn't need to load it by checking `map.Walkdirections`

hold your old Map as long as he is in Load range maybe he want to go back

```
            Map 1                Map 2
    --------------------- ---------------------
    |   |   |   |   |   | | X | X | X | X | X |
    --------------------- ---------------------
    |   |   |   |   |   | | P |   |   |   |   |
    --------------------- ---------------------
    |   |   |   |   |   | |   |   |   |   |   |
    --------------------- ---------------------
    |   |   |   |   |   | |   |   |   |   |   |   P = Player
    --------------------- ---------------------   X = Player can't pass this field
```

some thing to the P.Speed you should increase the loading range with the player speed

i hope this will help you
*by the way i don't know anything about XNA at the moment*

Comment: Ok, so the next map will only load when I'm close to triggering a map transition.  That's definitely useful, but it doesn't solve my null refrence from the refactor.

Comment: @ZeroPhase is your LoadContent() also refactored? if not you should check your `theContentManager` value because the are empty maybe you miss to fill. shouldn't it be empty post your `Load()` from `theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(theAssetName);`

Comment: @ZeroPhase oh i s you never initialize it `ContentManager theContentManager;`should maybe something like `ContentManager theContentManager = new ContentManager ();` because else it will always be null